# Django query in list view to group similar category records

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-orm

I have my website which displays the records on website these records are of different categories how can group the records belongs to similar category and display them together

category 1

1. List item 1
2. List item 2
3. List item 3

   ```
   class Mymixin:
       def get_queryset(self):

           return Record.objects.all()

   class Model:
       category = models.Charfield(max_length=255, choices=RecordsCategory.choices(True, True)
   ```

Comment: It is not a good idea to work with a `CharField`: you should make a `Category` model and work with a `ForeignKey` to that `Category` model as part of *database normalization* https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Thanks for the suggestion but Don't have that privilege can you suggest the same way it is

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem what if the Category is ForeignKey how can i query be

Comment: Please fix the english grammar in your question, it is hard to understand it. Also, how are you presenting the info? Admin site? Custom site? Custom API? You tagged django-rest-framework but I see no relation with this package. The code you provided is quite incomplete and disconnected. Why that mixin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just... order the records by category?

On how to do that: that depends on the nature of your website, which you didn't disclose, but at the end it will come to appending

```py
queryset = queryset.order_by('category')
```

to whatever queryset is feeding the website. Not that you need to write this as is: how this should be written will differ greatly depending on your actual site technology.